# Adding a further condition to a 3 table query in Mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Current query

```
SELECT vcc.name AS item, vcc.prodid, vcc.quantity AS qty,
       UPPER(vcc.custom_message) AS nickname, vfd1.value AS fullname,
       vfd2.value as email, vcc.purchaseid, vcc.price
FROM vxu_4_wpsc_cart_contents AS vcc INNER JOIN
     vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data AS vfd1
     ON vcc.purchaseid = vfd1.log_id AND vfd1.form_id = 2 INNER JOIN
     vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data AS vfd2
     ON vcc.purchaseid = vfd2.log_id AND vfd2.form_id = 9
```

I'm wanting to add the condition that the value in column 'processed' on table 'vxu_4_wpsc_purchase_logs is '2', so that only completed sales are returned. I'm struggling with the logic / syntax. Hope the image is readable.

[image: bigger image]

Comment: Can you include a larger version of that image? It's kind of hard to read the size it is now.

Comment: Hoping bigger image is readable ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. I've joined table purchase_logs by `id` and filtered result set by column `processed` with value equal `2`

```
SELECT vcc.name AS item, 
       vcc.prodid, 
       vcc.quantity AS qty,
       UPPER(vcc.custom_message) AS nickname, 
       vfd1.value AS fullname,
       vfd2.value as email, 
       vcc.purchaseid, 
       vcc.price
FROM vxu_4_wpsc_cart_contents AS vcc 
    INNER JOIN vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data AS vfd1 ON vcc.purchaseid = vfd1.log_id 
                                                            AND vfd1.form_id = 2 
    INNER JOIN vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data AS vfd2 ON vcc.purchaseid = vfd2.log_id 
                                                            AND vfd2.form_id = 9
    INNER JOIN vxu_4_wpsc_purchase_logs AS wpl ON wpl.id = vcc.purchaseid
WHERE wpl.processed = 2
```